# Trouble displaying output for Mini-Project

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm working on this mini-project involving twitter and I'm trying to get a list of the followers from the twitter user inputted. I was looking at Twitter's api and had done something similar to this before so I'm a bit befuddled why my console.log isn't outputting anything. Let me know if you have any questions and I posted the twitter api guide I was looking at.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

(I'm just console.logging the input for now but ideally will eventually put them in the output id)

Code below

HTML

```
 <h1>Scavengr<h1>

  <input class="from-control" id="mySearch">
   <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Generate </button>

  <ul id="output">

  </ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
                 $('#search').click(function(){
  var mySearch = $('#mySearch').val();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=' + $.param(mySearch),
                    headers:{
                    'Client-ID':'sample'
                  },
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data){
                      $('#output').html('');
                      for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++)
                        {
                          $('#output').prepend();
                          console.log(data[i].id);
                        }

                    }
                  });
                 });


  });
```

Let me know if you need anything else; I'm more than happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're trying to execute a GET to a different domain from a browser, which it will not allow unless they open up security for you (which is unlikely).  You will probably need to make some kind of proxy on your server and make the request from there, so it's not a cross domain service call.

Comment: I made a slight change where I added the API Key but it's still not working. Should that not fix it? (posted above)

Comment: First, delete your API key from this post.  You don't want others to have it.  Second, I don't think so.  You'll probably have to call it from the server, not within the browser, and then pass the data to the browser.  What's your back end written in?

Comment: I currently didn't have a back end. Was trying to keep it as light as possible and was just messing around in codepen for the time being.

Comment: I don't think it can be accomplished without Twitter opening up their API to cross site browser calls.